# В удаленном репозитории содержатся фиксации, не объединенные с локальной ветвью

Tags: git, netbeans

Подскажите, что может быть: "в удаленном репозитории содержатся фиксации, не объединенные с локальной ветвью"?

Работаю на NetBeans через git.

Comment: Вероятнее всего, есть какие-то конфликты. Конкретнее сформулируйте вопрос, какую операцию с гитом делаете, например, один ли вы работаете с репозиторием?

Comment: 99%, что удаленный репозиторий обновили, и его сначала надо выкачать к себе.

Comment: Работаю не один, я вытягиваю его с репозитория, потом фиксю и пытаюсь вытолкнуть, и вот такая беда.

Comment: Сделайте git pull, разрешите конфликты, если они возникли и потом git push. Желательно с консоли, гуй в топку.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

Сделайте git pull, разрешите конфликты, если они возникли и потом git push. Желательно с консоли, гуй в топку.

Answer (score 1):

Git - ветвь/тег - слияние редакций
далее  в обзоре выберите удаленную ветвь